# Feed hexdump to sed

Tags: sed, cat, hexdump

I have a file called samples.txt with 374371 lines that was created like this:

```
hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin > samples.txt
```

and it looks like this (deprecated):

```
1a 03 1a 03 4a 03 57 03
4b 03 44 03 1e 03 09 04
10 03 19 03 40 03 ae 03
1e 03 26 03 33 03 ad 03
10 03 84 03 43 03 62 03
e0 03 16 03 34 03 c4 03
f8 02 3b 03 53 03 61 03
10 03 15 03 42 03 58 03
23 03 1f 03 57 03 62 03
17 03 73 03 31 03 33 03
14 03 ff 02 30 03 51 03
5f 03 42 03 47 03 7e 03
ba 03 26 03 35 03 a0 03
08 03 33 03 36 03 c8 03
0c 03 38 03 97 03 44 03
```

and the following sed command:

```
echo "                ch0    ch1    ch2    ch3"; cat -n samples.txt | sed 's/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\)/Sample \1:\t0x\2\3 0x\4\5 0x\6\7 0x\8\9/' | head -n 15
```

gives me output that looks like this:

```
                ch0    ch1    ch2    ch3
Sample 1:       0x1a03 0x1a03 0x4a03 0x5703
Sample 2:       0x4b03 0x4403 0x1e03 0x0904
Sample 3:       0x1003 0x1903 0x4003 0xae03
Sample 4:       0x1e03 0x2603 0x3303 0xad03
Sample 5:       0x1003 0x8403 0x4303 0x6203
Sample 6:       0xe003 0x1603 0x3403 0xc403
Sample 7:       0xf802 0x3b03 0x5303 0x6103
Sample 8:       0x1003 0x1503 0x4203 0x5803
Sample 9:       0x2303 0x1f03 0x5703 0x6203
Sample 10:      0x1703 0x7303 0x3103 0x3303
Sample 11:      0x1403 0xff02 0x3003 0x5103
Sample 12:      0x5f03 0x4203 0x4703 0x7e03
Sample 13:      0xba03 0x2603 0x3503 0xa003
Sample 14:      0x0803 0x3303 0x3603 0xc803
Sample 15:      0x0c03 0x3803 0x9703 0x4403
```

It would seem to me, redirecting the output of hexdump to a temporary samples.txt file is inefficient, because for one you have to delete it at the end, and for two, perhaps using sed on the data in memory is faster than it would be on disk. How can I skip the samples.txt file and get the same results?

Comment: I have a vague idea why you cannot used direct piping, but to make your question clearer you might want to explain explicitly. I mean, I assume you did try that and did not like the result. Maybe discuss the difference of the result of what you tried and what you want.

Comment: Hi @Yunnosch, I modified my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work, if I understand your intentions correctly.

```
hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin | cat -n | sed '....
```

Comment: Hi @Dino Dini, I was actually going to try that, but I didn't think it would work. Thank you.

Comment: This works`echo "          ch0     ch1     ch2     ch3"; hexdump -e '8/1 "%02x " "\n"' samples.bin | cat -n | sed 's/\s*\([0-9]*\)\s*\([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\) \([0-9a-f]*\)/Sample \1:\t0x\2\3\t0x\4\5\t0x\6\7\t0x\8\9/'` Thanks @Dino Dini

Answer (score 0):

Alternative with `xxd` and coreutils:

```bash
{
  # Print header
  printf "\t\tCh0    Ch1    Ch2    Ch3\n"

  # Create hexdump of data
  xxd -p samples.bin       |

  # Use 16 bit samples
  fold -w4                 |

  # Add hex indicator
  sed 's/^/0x/'            |

  # Data contains 4 interleaved channels
  xargs -n4                |

  # Number each sample
  nl -n ln                 |
  sed 's/ /:/; s/^/Sample /'
} > samples.out
```

Content of `samples.out`:

```
                Ch0    Ch1    Ch2    Ch3
Sample 1:       0x1a03 0x1a03 0x4a03 0x5703
Sample 2:       0x4b03 0x4403 0x1e03 0x0904
Sample 3:       0x1003 0x1903 0x4003 0xae03
Sample 4:       0x1e03 0x2603 0x3303 0xad03
Sample 5:       0x1003 0x8403 0x4303 0x6203
Sample 6:       0xe003 0x1603 0x3403 0xc403
Sample 7:       0xf802 0x3b03 0x5303 0x6103
Sample 8:       0x1003 0x1503 0x4203 0x5803
Sample 9:       0x2303 0x1f03 0x5703 0x6203
Sample 10:      0x1703 0x7303 0x3103 0x3303
Sample 11:      0x1403 0xff02 0x3003 0x5103
Sample 12:      0x5f03 0x4203 0x4703 0x7e03
Sample 13:      0xba03 0x2603 0x3503 0xa003
Sample 14:      0x0803 0x3303 0x3603 0xc803
Sample 15:      0x0c0a 0x3803 0x9703 0x4403
```

Comment: Hi @Thor, love your comments and use of `\t` for tab, fold was a nice solution too. I suppose we could even do like so `printf "\t\tCh0\tCh1\tCh2\tCh3\n"`. I changed your script like `nl -v 0 -n ln` to start the first line at 0. The only issue is that this script runs slowly. I have discovered the use of mawk and I got the whole thing to run in 4 seconds. I forgot to mention that the samples.bin file contains 374371 lines.